# Upload file to a user after it was changed on server

Tags: php, jquery, download

What I'm trying to do is to change a file with user's input and upload updated file back to user.

for now i have some java script that collects data from inputs :

```
$('#collectButton').click(function() {
    var inputs = $('#someDiv input').get();
```

Since I collect data I need to send it to my PHP code, it's done by ajax Post and JSON (array transfer).

```
$.ajax({
       type: "POST",
        url: "Some.php",
        data: {postedData:JSON.stringify(inputs)},
    success: function()
            {
        alert('done!');                            
            }
    });
```

Firebug console confirms data transfer and here comes the problem:

In response I see the changed file (simple txt) that SHOULD be uploaded back, but it's not.

PHP that I use is:

```
if (isset ($_POST['postedData'])){
      $changes = (json_decode( $_POST['postedData']));
    ....
    some changes done by for loop
    ....

        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($nwFile));
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($nwFile));
        ob_clean();
        flush();
        readfile($nwFile);
        // deletes file right after
        fclose($nwFile);
        unlink($nwFile);
```

How to do it correct??

Why the "header" part of PHP ignored??

PS

Stand alone PHP file works grate.

problem appears only in "calling PHP"

Comment: Have you confirmed that $nwFile is in fact created on the server? also,  why are you calling ob_clean() right after the headers?

Comment: Yaniro - Yes $nwFile is created
ob_clean() - is that a problem?? it's Cleaning the output buffer. i don't need buffer, all the data in file.

Comment: Try using ob_clean() before the headers but do you really need it?

Comment: I don't need to use it at all??? I will try to remove it.

Comment: It's one line, try removing it, it takes less time than writing a comment on SO :), but i can see that you've taken the code from php.net example so it must be fine... what happens when you run the script? you get nothing? you get the file outputted to the browser? nothing happens? what do you see when you view the source of the output in the browser? Also, what is the file name used in $nwFile? does it include spaces?

Comment: POST ../Uploadchange.php 200 OK

Post

inputs ["asd","sdasd",null,"sadas","sadsa","141","64-bit","shared","ascii"]
Source
inputs=%5B%22asd%22%2C%22sdasd%22%2Cnull%2C%22sadas%22%2C%22sadsa%22%2C%22141%22%2C%2264-bit%22%2C%22shared%22%2C%22ascii%22%5D

Response

asd
sdasd
sadas

Comment: there is no problem in data transfer. problem in getting file uploaded. it's find of ajax receiving file back instead of uploading it to user.

Comment: Oh oh, i think i just realised what the problem is... the file is being sent back to jQuery's ajax functions which have nothing to do with binary file data.  In order for the browser to realise that a file needs to be downloaded, you need to redirect the browser to the file instead of doing it in ajax.  If you need to keep the user in the same page, try submitting a form with the appropriate parameters  (the file generating the script & the parameters needed to create the file) to a hidden iframe.

Comment: Yaniro you right! I HAVE to keep user on the same page. What paramiters have to be?  Can you give some example?? what should be in iFrame? I'm really new to this .

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick example:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <iframe name="fileDownload" style="position: absolute; visibility: hidden;"></iframe>
        <form action="download.php" method="post" target="fileDownload">
            <input type="hidden" id="postedData" name="postedData" value="some data">
            <input type="submit"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Please note that i've created a hidden inline-frame (iframe) with a distinct name.
The form on the page submits a parameter called postedData to a file download.php which will be executed in the hidden iframe.
download.php should take the parameter, generate the file and send the appropriate headers & content.  You can also remove the style="..." from the iframe and see what's going on in the iframe and debug stuff if necessary.

You can set the content of the postedData parameter like so:

```
function setData( data )
{
    document.getElementById( "postedData" ).value = data;
}
```

I've tested this on Chrome, FireFox 3.6, Explorer 8 & Oper and it works fine.

Comment: This is not what I need actually. This is a direct way to transfer data. I need pre-check and pre-set data to in correct order before transmit it to PHP, so have to use JS first.

Comment: What does "pre-check and pre-set data to in correct order" mean?

Answer (score 0):

I used a script from this site http://tutorialzine.com/2011/05/generating-files-javascript-php/, adapted it a bit and it works fine for me.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $('#download').click(function(e){

            $.generateFile({
                filename    : 'export.txt',
                content     : $('textarea').val(),
                script      : 'download.php'
            });

            e.preventDefault();
        });}

(function($){

    // Creating a jQuery plugin:

        $.generateFile = function(options){

            options = options || {};

            if(!options.script || !options.filename || !options.content){
                throw new Error("Please enter all the required config options!");
            }

            // Creating a 1 by 1 px invisible iframe:

            var iframe = $('<iframe>',{
                width:1,
                height:1,
                frameborder:0,
                css:{
                    display:'none'
                }
            }).appendTo('body');

            var formHTML = '<form action="" method="post">'+
                '<input type="hidden" name="filename" />'+
                '<input type="hidden" name="content" />'+
                '</form>';

            // Giving IE a chance to build the DOM in
            // the iframe with a short timeout:

            setTimeout(function(){

                // The body element of the iframe document:

                var body = (iframe.prop('contentDocument') !== undefined) ?
                                iframe.prop('contentDocument').body :
                                iframe.prop('document').body;   // IE

                body = $(body);

                // Adding the form to the body:
                body.html(formHTML);

                var form = body.find('form');

                form.attr('action',options.script);
                form.find('input[name=filename]').val(options.filename);
                form.find('input[name=content]').val(options.content);

                // Submitting the form to download.php. This will
                // cause the file download dialog box to appear.

                form.submit();
            },50);
        };

    })(jQuery);
```